# How to use intent.getExtras() in Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent

My class extends from `Fragment`, I want to add a parameter to other class.
So, I was using this code to do this.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AddContactActivity.class);
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putString("numberPhone", phoneNumber);
b.putString("timeStart", startTime);
intent.getExtras(b);
startActivity(intent);
```

But this show error like:

> error: method getExtras in class Intent cannot be applied to given types;
>
> required: no arguments
>
> found: Bundle
>
> reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Comment: you want to use intent.putExtra("name", b) , not getExtra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want set the data bundle in an `Intent` you should use -

```
putExtras(Bundle bundle)
```

like -

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AddContactActivity.class);
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putString("numberPhone", phoneNumber);
b.putString("timeStart", startTime);
intent.putExtras(b);
startActivity(intent);
```